# Showing a relationship is transitive

Tags: elementary-set-theory, relations, equivalence-relations

I can't figure out why the following relationship is transitive:

> Consider the relation $R=\left\{(a,a),(b,b),(c, c),(d,d),(a,b),(b,a)\right\}$ on set $A =\left\{a,b, c,d\right\}$.
>   Is $R$ reflexive? Symmetric? Transitive? If a property does not hold, say why.

Comment: Needs more exclamation points.

Comment: The use of caps lock is considered "shouting" in internet language. http://www.netlingo.com/word/shouting.php

Comment: internet language is no language, who said to whom, that caps lock means shouting.

Comment: Well, if you wanted to shout on the internet, how would you do it? Wouldn't writing in all caps occur to you as a way to shout on the internet?

Comment: @maths Seeing as you're seeking help, it would be better for you to be polite & take correction.

Answer (score 1):

A relation is transitive if $(a,b),(b,c) \in R \rightarrow (a,c) \in R$. In your case it suffices to try out all the possible combinations. Note that only elements with $a,b$ may give rise to any problems, because all others are pairs of two equal elements.

Answer (score 0):

The relation $R$ is reflexive because $\forall x$, $xRx$, $(x,x)\in R$ 
The relation $R$ is symmetric because in every case that $xRy$, $yRx$
The relation $R$ is transitive because indeed in every case where $xRy \land yRz$ is true, indeed $xRz$ is true.